# Rewrite rule in WAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

I am using a WAMP Server. I need to apply rewrite rule for the pages in my local system. I have enabled the rewrite_rule from the WAMP icon at Task bar.

My Website path in local system is `http://localhost/Kitty_Enfin/`.

```
http://localhost/Test/index.php -> http://localhost/Test/home
http://localhost/Test/index.php?do=main -> http://localhost/Test/main
http://localhost/Test/index.php?do=profile&uid=1 -> http://localhost/Test/profile/1
```

Above are the pages I need to rewrite.

**My question is:** where I need to place the .htaccess file?

- Whether in www/ or www/Test
- What is the .htaccess Rewrite rule for the above

It will be more helpful if anyone helps on the Following issue.

---

---

Thank you for your reply. When I used the above it not worked for me. But I used another rewrite rule which works for the first two:

`RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /\Test/\index\.php [L]` - Working
 (`http://localhost/Test`, `http://localhost/Test/index`)

`RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /\Test/\index.php?do=$1 [L]` - Working
 (`http://localhost/Test/main`)

`RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+)?$ /\Test/\index.php?do=profile&uid=$1` - Working but the CSS and other scripts are not work here.

And also the links in the pages are `http://localhost/Test/profile/` instead of `http://localhost/Test/`.

Do you have any idea on this issue? Please correct me if I did anything wrong.

Do you have any idea on this issue. Please correct me any thing i did wrong
Thanks

Comment: Sorry Sukumar i am a begineer and i m learning these things for the first time. I search on internet and i have make for of two links as explained above but for the third one i dont get any clue or idea ITs working but the css and scripts are not linked

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule ^/?index.php                    home/
RewriteRule ^/?index.php?do=(\w*)           $1/
RewriteRule ^/?index.php?do=(\w*)&uid=(\w*) $1/$2
```

**place the .htaccess in "Test" folder**

I can only answer this from your clue